# Boost MPI and serialization - size of serialized object

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, mpi

At my university I have to measure the overhead of the serialization of C++ STL types that are sent using MPI.

Measuring the time is easy, but I have a problem if I would want to measure for example how much bytes is needed to send a `vector` of 1000 chars and array of 1000 chars for example. Looking at the `Boost.MPI` docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.user_data_types
I can see that it uses `Boost.Serialization` for serialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/

`Boost.Serialization` uses archives for during serialization, but I can't see if there is a way I can extract from archive the amount of bytes it takes? I am not very familiar with boost docs so I may be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);

    std::vector<char> v(1000);

    // stream
    oa << v;

    std::cout << "The number of bytes taken for the vector in an archive is " << oss.str().size() << "\n";
}
```

On my system it prints:

```
The number of bytes taken for the vector in an archive is 1048
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72a33d2fc3acd6ad)**

It's possible that MPI's `packed_oarchive` does additional compression. I haven't found this in the docs on a quick scan.